# Finding the maximum value of $y=\frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2-x+1}$ without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

The problem is:

> Find the maximum value of
> $$y=\frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2-x+1}$$ assuming $x\geq 0$. I am only interested in pre-calculus solutions.

Using calculus it is easy to see that the maximum is $y=\frac{5}{3}$ occuring at $x=2$.

Other forms are

$$y=\frac{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{3}{4}}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{5}{4}}$$
$$y=\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})+1}{(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to rewrite it as a quadratic for $x$

$$ (y-1)x^2 - (y+1)x + (y+1)=0$$

And require that the discriminant be not negative

$$(y+1)^2 - 4(y+1)(y-1) \ge 0$$
$$(y - \frac{5}{3})(y+1) \le 0$$

Which gives us the range for $y$.  To be thorough, it's also good to check that the maximum value for $y$ does not correspond to a zero in the denominator of the original fraction.  In this case, it doesn't.